# Creating ERD for the database

Tags: database-design, erd

I'm trying to create erd base on https://vod.shaw.ca.

As a entity, I came up with `Price`, `Rental`, `Customer`, `Wishlist`
and with `Rental`, there is another relationship with `Movie_title`, `Movie_Category`.

This is my ERD

[image: ERD]

My question is, I'm not sure rather I need to include `Refund` in my ERD or not.

I thought refund could be one of the attribute for the `Rental`, but in someway it could be another table.

Also, I would love to know if there is any suggested correction for my ERD (verb and relationship).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option1**: *Refund* should be an attribute of **Rental** table because whenever a movie rental canceled, user update **Rental** table record by updating single column value named Refund from false to true.

It should be done if no further information is required.

Insertion: You will need to write queries for insertion related to rental only
Deletion: You cannot keep record of refunds if rental deleted.
Updation: Must write UPDATE query later.

**Option2**. **Refund** should be a table if information is required to view the detail of person who return movie and there a separate form to input detail for this table.

Insertion: You will need to write queries for insertion related to refund only
Deletion: You cannot keep record of rental if refund deleted.

So All is depend upon requirements of the system users.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try harder to avoid using the word 'has' all over the place.

It may be the case that 'wishlist' is actually a many-many relationship between customer and title (any number of titles may appear on a customer's wishlist and a title may be on any number of customer's wishlists).

It may be the case that you want to rethink that entire rental/price thing.  What on earth does that relationship represent in the first place ?

And as for the Refund thing : if you don't tell us what kind of information is being denoted here (e.g. do you intend this to be some Y/N flag indicating that some refund has been done, or is this intended to be some amount that got refunded on some date, or still something else ?), no serious professional can give you any serious answer.